# R - How can I calculate a matrix with a function?

Tags: r, function, matrix, vector

i have a problem with following code in R. I want `myfun()` function to write some data into the `my.res` matrix. I can print the statement `my.vec[i]/my.vec[i-j]` easily.

```
my.vec <-c(1:10)
my.res <-matrix( ,10,2)

myfun <-function(j=2){

  for(i in (j+1):10){

    my.res[i,1] <-my.vec[i]/my.vec[i-j]

    print(my.vec[i]/my.vec[i-j])

  }
}
```

Comment: You don't need a loop, just do `my.res[(j+1):10, 1] <-my.vec[(j + 1):10]/my.vec[((j+1):10) - j]`, R is vectorized.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your print in the wrong location, also changed your input `j=2` to simply `j` that can be assigned. As mentioned - you don't need a loop to do this - but seems like you are just trying to learn how to work with loops?

```
myfun <- function(j){
  for(i in (j + 1):10){
    my.res[i,1] <- my.vec[i]/my.vec[i-j]
  }
  print(my.res)
}

myfun(2)
```